# How seriously will "related" areas be considered?

Tags: faculty-application

In ads about faculty positions, I often read phrases like "We are seeking candidates with interests in X, Y, and Z, but other related areas will also be considered"

In such cases, do candidates not specialized in X, Y or Z have a chance? Or how "exceptional" do they have to be in order to have a chance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to your (real) question is: Apply anyway. A department's hiring strategy is many times not fully expressed by an ad, never mind the fact that it's something in constant motion.

Comment: This is the correct answer. There is simply no way to tell from the ad whether the stated research areas are absolute requirements, mild preferences, meaningless admnistratve boilerplate, or inaccurate leftovers from three years ago that someone forgot to edit. **Just apply.**

Comment: Ironically I feel like if OP asked their "real" question that it would have closed as too specific.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my understanding, that generally means that they really do want a candidate in X, Y, and Z.

However, every candidate and every search is unique, and it might turn out to be the case that somebody good with an unusual combination that doesn't exactly match X, Y, and Z turns up, or that a candidate who is just too good to miss turns up, or that something changes internally during the search process (searches are often negotiated with a university far in advance), or some other such unexpected circumstance.  If something like this does come to pass, then the "related areas" clause lets them make the hiring decision they want, even if it doesn't match what was originally written.

Bottom line: yes, there is a chance, but it is probably very very small.